# Need help on populating Text area field from a string containing multiselect picklist values separated by comma

Tags: apex

This is my code:

```
Public with sharing class SeparatePotNameHelper {
 Public static void getSeparatePotPicklistValue(List<Agreement_Extensions_VMN__c> aggectvmnlist)
    { 
      System.debug('aggectvmnlist'+aggectvmnlist);
      List<String> PotSet = new List<String>();
      for(Agreement_Extensions_VMN__c aev:aggectvmnlist)
        {
          PotSet.add(aev.Separate_Pot__c);
        }
           String st = String.valueOf(PotSet);
           String st1 = st.replace(';',',');
           System.debug('st1 values'+st1);
        }

}
```

now how to insert "st1" values into a text area field on the same object.
Kindly assist....Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You just need to set the value on your respective text area field and make an update call. I don't see that you have attempted to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `List<String> PotSet = new List<String>();` from the code and directly assign st1 to the text area field inside the for loop.

Please check below updated code -

`for(Agreement_Extensions_VMN__c aev : aggectvmnlist){
    String seperatePot = String.valueOf(aev.Separate_Pot__c);
    String st = String.isNotBlank(seperatePot)? seperatePot : '';
    String st1 = st.replace(';',',');
    aev.textAreaFieldHere__c = st1;
}`

`update aggectvmnlist;`